# onchange event is not woking on flatpickr() input

Tags: html, jquery, flatpickr

I have created a **date picker** with `flatpickr()` date picker is working fine. but I am trying to create an `onchange` event on that date picker but `onchange` event is not working I had tried to make a function like myfunction and call it on the input it is also not working

so can anybody help me in this

```js
$(".flatpickr").flatpickr();
$("#flatpickr-disable-range").flatpickr({
  disable: [
    { from: "2016-08-16", to: "2016-08-19" },
    "2016-08-24", new Date().fp_incr(30) // 30 days from now
  ]
});
$(".flatpickr").change(function() {
  alert("Handler for .change() called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.7/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control flatpickr" id="set_exam_date" data-min-date="today" data-date-format="D F j, Y" placeholder="Select Date">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the order of your scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.7/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
```

Then you forgot the jQuery sign before searching for flatpickr:

```
$( ".flatpickr" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Comment: it is still not alerting

Comment: https://codepen.io/Madness1985/pen/zQrode in my case it calls the alert (change the date)

Answer (score 0):

You have to init a jQuery and flatpickr below your HTML code. You should use it in the body at the end. Like this:

```js
 $('.flatpickr').flatpickr();
        $("#flatpickr-disable-range").flatpickr({
          disable: [{
              from: "2016-08-16",
              to: "2016-08-19"
            },
            "2016-08-24",
            new Date().fp_incr(30) // 30 days from now
          ]
        });
        $(".flatpickr").change(function () {
          alert("Handler for .change() called.");
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control flatpickr" id="set_exam_date" data-min-date="today" data-date-format="D F j, Y"
          placeholder="Select Date">
      </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.7/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript vanilla.
For example, I use the flatpick version on vanilla js.

```js
flatpickr(".flatpickr", {});

document.querySelector(".flatpickr").onchange = function() {        
        alert("Hello");
        };
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<input class="flatpickr" type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

[check with flatpicker document](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/)

```
  flatpickr(".datepicker" ,{
    onChange:function (){
      //date change function hear
    }
  });
```